# How to create an Alert with don't show this again option in a centralized Alerts class

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have an Alerts class where I define all alert windows of my app with methods in this forms

```
   public static void Alert1(Context con) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
            builder.setTitle("my title");
            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
            DialogListner listner = new DialogListner();
            builder.setMessage("my message");
            builder.setPositiveButton("ok", listner);

            AlertDialog diag = builder.create();
            diag.show();
    }
```

Now I want to create in a similar way also an Alert windows with a checkBox ***"Don't show this again"*** that if is selected avoid the view of this Alert

Answer (score 3):

I have a clarity and right approach for this question

```
package com.example.user.testing;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CheckBox dontShowAgain;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile1";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater adbInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View eulaLayout = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox, null);

    dontShowAgain = (CheckBox) eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.skip);
    adb.setView(eulaLayout);
    adb.setTitle("Attention");
    adb.setMessage("Your message here");
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("skipMessage", dontShowAgain.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    Boolean skipMessage = settings.getBoolean("skipMessage", false);
    if (skipMessage.equals(false)) {
        adb.show();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Oh so you have clarity? I would love you to ell me more about your clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the application `SharedPreference` object. Add an item in you shared preference, by trying to read it for the first time. The all you have to do is put a value to the object and just check it every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate layout for your dialog with this checkbox and textview. Inflate this layout and add set it as view for your dialog

well it would be something like below.

```
View view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.dialogView,null);
//and set to your dialog
dialog.setView(view);

//Or you can set it to your builder also
```

And handle onCheckListener for checkbox

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, you should create a custom layout with the desired message and controls (Checkbox), and use `SharedPreferences` to keep track of the user choice

Here are 2 blog posts that describes these topics.
[Creating and Displaying a Custom Dialog in Android](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/creating-and-displaying-a-custom-dialog-in-android/)
[Writing and Reading from SharedPreferences](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/writing-and-reading-from-sharedpreferences/)
(Disclaimer: my blog.)